# inject a react component as background-image

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for the best way to inject a dynamically built image as my background image.  I can build the image and I can display it as a div but I want it as the background of my body.

```
    <div className="App">
    <mycomonent />
    </div>
```

works but it is not what I want

```
     <body styles="background-image: {mycomponent}"></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change using regular DOM object within React.

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url("https://www.placecage.com/c/460/300")`;
```

Working Demo 
[image: Edit n7mnw40xml]